# SSRS Hide Item in Legend based on conditions

Tags: reporting-services, legend

I have a problem related to the legend you can make use of in an SSRS report.

I have a stacked bar diagram in my report, let us call the groups series for Category. The bar chart will display as following:

Category A

Category B

Category C

Category D

...

I have different filters in this report which will only display two categories sometimes, e.g. Cat. A and Cat B. The problem is that the legend still will display all categories even if it is not displayed in the bar chart due to certain conditions made by the users.

I have tried a lot now but without any result. How can i display only Categories in the legend that only exists in the bar?

BR,

Nicklas

Comment: The chart will show the data you have. It seems like the categories are still there with no values. Can you give more detail, like the SQL you are using for the chart?

Answer (score 4):

Right-click on a chart bar, select "Series Properties", choose Legend and click "fx" sign next to "Do not show this series in a legend". Make an expression, which hides legend for this chart bar, if the value is NULL or zero. Here you have an example" http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/0e145eb1-924c-488f-95b1-56028c4f03a8

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on a chart bar, select "Series Properties", choose "Visibility", Select "Show or hide based on an expression", Give your condition(by clicking fx sign you will find condition pane). Example : If you want to show only not null values-

`=IIf(Fields!Cat_A.Value is nothing,true,false)`